# Finding number of paths using combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

[image]

The problem is already stated on the picture and I have already found the answer but I have no idea how to solve it mathematically. I'm aware that the use of combinations is required here. I came up with $6c3$, but then if I think it properly there are $7$ moves in total not $6$ which is why I'm really confused. The rectangles are what's stumping me. Please help

Answer (score 1):

The method depicted in your diagram is a legitimate mathematical argument.  You counted the number of direct paths Bea could take by working backwards from point B, with the number of backwards paths at each intersection being equal to the sum of the number of paths from the right and from below.  Had I been using that argument, I would have worked in the opposite direction, but it would not have affected the answer.

Bea must walk four blacks to the right and three blocks down to reach point B from point A.  If each street went through, then any direct path would consist of four rightward moves and three downward moves.  Such a path would be completely determined by choosing which three of those seven moves were downwards.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{7}{3}$$
such paths.

However, Second Avenue and Third Avenue do not go through.  Therefore, we must subtract those paths which would connect River Walk and Board Walk via Second Avenue and those paths which would connect Gateway Boulevard and Crest Boulevard via Third Avenue.  Doing so takes some care since it is possible that if the streets did go through, Bea could walk both those blocks.  If we simply subtract the number of paths which would connect River Walk and Board Walk via Second Avenue and those paths which would connect Gateway Boulevard and Crest Boulevard via Third Avenue, we will have subtracted those paths which would go through both of these blocked blocks twice.  We only want to subtract them once, so we will have to add them back.  This is an application of the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Counting paths which would connect River Walk and Board Walk via Second Avenue:  There is only one way for Bea to reach the imaginary corner of River Walk and Second Avenue from point A. There is also only one way for her to walk the imaginary block of Second Avenue which would connect River Walk and Board Walk.  Thus, if the remaining streets were all connected, she would have to walk three blocks to the right and two blocks downwards to reach point B directly.  How many such paths are there?

> She must choose which two of the five moves required for her to walk from the corner of Board Walk and Second Avenue to point B will be downwards, which can be done in $$\binom{5}{2}$$ ways.

Counting paths which would connect Gateway Boulevard and Crest Boulevard via Third  Avenue:  If each street went through, Bea would have to walk three blocks to the right and two blocks downwards to reach the corner of Gateway Boulevard and Third Avenue.  In how many ways can she do this?  Once she makes those choices, there is only one way for her to walk the imaginary block of Third Avenue which would connect Gateway Boulevard and Crest Boulevard and only one way for her to walk the block from the imaginary corner of Third Avenue and Crest Boulevard to point B.

> She must choose which two of the five moves required for her to move from point A to the corner of Gateway Boulevard and Third Avenue would be downward, which can be done in $$\binom{5}{2}$$ ways.

Counting paths which would connect River Walk and Board Walk via Second Avenue and connect Gateway Boulevard and Crest Boulevard via Third  Avenue: There is only one way for Bea to reach the corner of Board Walk and Second Avenue via the imaginary block of Second Avenue which would connect River Walk and Board Walk.  She would then have to walk two blocks to the right and one block downwards to reach the corner of Third Avenue and Gateway Boulevard.  In how many ways can she do this?  There is only one way for her to walk from the corner of Third Avenue and Gateway Boulevard to point B via the imaginary block of Third Avenue which would connect Gateway Boulevard and Crest Boulevard.

> She must choose which of the three moves required to move from the corner of Board Walk and Second Avenue to the corner of Gateway Boulevard would be downwards, which can be done in $$\binom{3}{1}$$ ways.

Finally, apply the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

> $$\binom{7}{3} - \binom{5}{2} - \binom{5}{2} + \binom{3}{1} = 18$$